# I did make or I made

Tags: writing

Sometimes when i was communicating with English speakers they was using different past. Someone said me that i should use "I made" if I`m actually speaking about past. And now I wanna know what is the actual different.

Comment: Please see: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118683/difference-between-did-verb-and-just-verbed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal to use "I made" over "I did make". If you say "I did make something", it is inferred that there is an implied emphasis on the word "did" (i.e. "I ***did*** make something"); it comes across as if you are trying to convince someone of your action rather than just stating your action.

It is a small distinction to be perfectly honest, but an important one. Both mean the same thing, but there is different subtext to each phrase.

Answer (score 0):

The simple past would be “I made.” You might use “I did make” if you want to emphasize your action:
“I made that cake.”
“No you didn’t!”
Yes! I DID make that cake!”